# Click spacebar action in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, function

Is is possible in Swift to create an action for clicking the space button?

Sorta like:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
 // Do somthing
}
```

But instead of clicking return, then space?
Like:

```
func textFieldShouldSpace(textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
  // Do Something?
}
```

Comment: there is no action for "clicking the space button" what you want to do is react when the user insert a special character into the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` and look to see if the proposed new character (the replacement string) is a space.